# exception thrown after reinizialisizing a SQLite database

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have a problem to reinizialize SQLite database on Android.

my exception:

```
        15152/ch.companyname.projectname E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
     Process: ch.companyname.projectname, PID: 15117
     java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
         at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:325)
         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
         at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
      Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase: /data/user/0/ch.companyname.projectname/files/db_de.sqlite
         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteClosable.acquireReference(SQLiteClosable.java:55)
         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1349)
         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1292)
         at com.j256.ormlite.android.compat.JellyBeanApiCompatibility.rawQuery(JellyBeanApiCompatibility.java:21)
         at com.j256.ormlite.android.AndroidCompiledStatement.getCursor(AndroidCompiledStatement.java:193)
         at com.j256.ormlite.android.AndroidCompiledStatement.runQuery(AndroidCompiledStatement.java:72)
         at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.SelectIterator.<init>(SelectIterator.java:57)
         at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.StatementExecutor.buildIterator(StatementExecutor.java:247)
         at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.StatementExecutor.query(StatementExecutor.java:197)
         at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.query(BaseDaoImpl.java:277)
         at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.QueryBuilder.query(QueryBuilder.java:366)
         at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.Where.query(Where.java:480)
         at ch.companyname.projectname.business.database.DatabaseAccessBackend$5.queryInBackground(DatabaseAccessBackend.java:151)
         at ch.companyname.projectname.business.database.DatabaseAccessBackend$5.queryInBackground(DatabaseAccessBackend.java:144)
         at ch.companyname.projectname.business.database.QueryTask.doInBackground(QueryTask.java:28)
         at ch.companyname.projectname.business.database.QueryTask.doInBackground(QueryTask.java:11)
         at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:305)
         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
         at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243) 
         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

As I found out, this exception occurs when multiple instances of sqlite are open. https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-lite-android/issues/1009

My Helper methods:

```
 private DatabaseHelper getHelper() {
    String locale = AppSettingsBackend.getInstance(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)).getAppSettings().get().getLanguage();
    if (this.databaseHelper == null || databaseLocale != locale) {
        destroyCurrentHelper();

        this.databaseLocale = locale;
        DatabaseHelper.DATABASE_LOCALE = locale;
        this.databaseHelper = OpenHelperManager.getHelper(context, DatabaseHelper.class);
    }
    return this.databaseHelper;
}

private void destroyCurrentHelper() {
    if (this.databaseHelper != null) {
        databaseHelper.close();
        databaseHelper = null;
    }
}
```

Code in DatabaseAccessBackend around line 151:

```
public void getNavigationItemsForParentId(final int parentId, final QueryTask.Callback<List<NavigationItem>> callback, final List<Integer> ignoreIds) {
    new QueryTask<List<NavigationItem>>() {
        @Override
        protected List<NavigationItem> queryInBackground() throws SQLException {
            Where<NavigationItem, Integer> query = getHelper().getNavigationItemDao().queryBuilder().where().eq("ZPARENTID", parentId);
            if (ignoreIds != null && ignoreIds.size() > 0) {
                query.and().notIn("ZID", ignoreIds);
            }
            return query.query();
        }
    }.start(callback);
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code at/around `at ch.companyname.projectname.business.database.DatabaseAccessBackend$5.queryInBackground(DatabaseAccessBackend.java:151)`

Comment: the method getNavigationItemforParentId work. only crash when i have changed the database.

Comment: I found out that it works the first time. only when I change the database for the second time does this exception occur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the mistake:

just change

```
databaseHelper.close()
```

to

```
OpenHelperManager.releaseHelper();
```